# Using hero card buttons without calling bot

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I've run into a case where I need to show two buttons using a Hero Card without interacting the bot. Until now I have used the below in my previous project

```
var heroCard = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = "Please select",
                Buttons = new List<CardAction> { new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "q1", value: "show answer a"),
                            new CardAction(ActionTypes.PostBack, "q2", value: "show answer b"),
            };
            return heroCard.ToAttachment();
```

Based on this if you select any button, it will PostBack and send the corresponding value to the bot. Now my new case is that when user press a button I will send its value directly to the MessageReceivedAsync task where I am checking the activity text. How can I send the button's value as the activity text directly to the MessageReceivedAsync task without sending it also to the bot?

Comment: Simply put, you cant. Your method is part of the bot and thus you will have tp go throughthe bot and the dialog stack to get there. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: On button click I want to show back an unordered list of text depending of course which button is pressed

Comment: When you say you don't want to send the button click to the bot, do you just  mean when the user clicks the button, you dont want the button text to appear on the bot client? You jsut want the bot to process the click and return a response?

Comment: No, that is the issue. By clicking the button the reply is sent to the bot which responses based on some python code. Now I want to avoid that. On button click I want only some c# code to run and return a  standard text. Click button 1, response text1, click button 2, response text2. Maybe by using a hero card I can't avoid the interaction with the bot but I am no 100% sure about this.

Comment: Ok, then your are correct. You can't really bypass the bot using bot framework built bots. You might be able to do something at the webchat client level but that would be a considerably complex task.